# Release and dispose all http scoped objects in Structuremap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I'm creating a small application that I will distribute via NuGet. My web app is using Structuremap for DI and in my global.asax I have this snippet:

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest() {
    ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
}
```

is it possible to hook this up in another way without modifying the global.asax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write an [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) which could be registered in web.config:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule 
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application) 
    {
        application.EndRequest += Application_EndRequest;
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) 
    {
        ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
    }        

    public void Dispose() 
    {
    }
}
```

and in web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="MyModule" type="AppName.MyModule, AppName" />
</httpModules>
```

<strike>Another, more MVCish way would be to write a global action filter:</strike>

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
    }
}
```

which could be registered in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method of `Global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());
}
```

Comment: You can also register your module without having to edit web.config: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html